# "Packet needs to be fragmented by DF set." issue when I ping my NAS, synology 1511+

Tags: networking, nas, ping

I have a synology 1511+ nas. My network transfer speeds are very slow, < 1meg a sec in some cases. It's next to unbearable.

Anyway was reading about this thing that said to ping it using the -f settings and here's the result.

```
C:\Users\Jason Fonseca>ping -f -l 2000 192.168.1.139

Pinging 192.168.1.139 with 2000 bytes of data:
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.139:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

The website said to adjust the MTU settings in order to get rid of this message but I don't know what to change.

Can anyone recommend what needs to be done here?

Jase

Comment: Is WLAN or another wireless technology involved somehow?

Answer (score 1):

```
>ping -f -l 2000 192.168.1.139
```

This command tries to send 2000 Bytes at once, while an ethernet frame can transmit only a bit less than 1500 Bytes by default.

Changing the MTU of your Ethernet card is **not recommended** unless you know *exactly* what you do.

One reason is that every switch/bridge between your PC and the NAS must support the bigger MTU too. And your ethernet card may not even have the capability to send/receive ethernet frames bigger than 1500 Bytes.

Comment: That is the whole point of this command to test the support for the jumbo frames. Changing the MTU is required for Jumbo Frame support - so the question should have been what does it mean and what do I need to do to fix it.
However your answer still does not answer the ops question.